# Extra numbers being appended to string, don't know why?

Tags: c++, string

```
Number(string binary)
        {
            int raw_string_int[size];
            char raw_string_char[size];
            strcpy(raw_string_char,binary.c_str());
            printf("Raw String is %s",raw_string_char);

                for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
                {

                    raw_string_int[i] = int(raw_string_char[i]);
                    printf("%i\n",int(raw_string_char[i]));
                    if (raw_string_int[i] != 0 || raw_string_int[i] != 1)
                    {
                        printf("ERROR NOT A BINARY NUMBER\n");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
```

Hi, I'm entering 0001 as binary at the command prompt, but raw_string_char is being appended with two extra numbers. Can anyone explain to me why this is? Is the carriage return being brought in as a char?

Here is What I'm getting at the command prompt:

```
./test
0001
Raw String is 000148
ERROR NOT A BINARY NUMBER
```

Answer (score 9):

You forgot the "\n" in your first printf.  The 48 is from the second printf, and is the result of casting the first '0' (ASCII 0x30 = 48) to an int.

To convert a textual 0 or 1 to the corresponding integer, you need to subtract 0x30.

Comment: I included a \n in the printf statement... that seems to have solved the problem somewhat. I now get the correct value for Raw String Is 0001. However a 48 is printing out after that and I dont know why. Can you maybe go into a little more detail on why the printf statement would alter the value of an array?

Comment: To convert a textual digit to a corresponding integer, prefer subtracting `'0'` rather than 0x30.  0x30 is the ASCII code for '0'; but when switching to other text coding scheme, 0x30 may not work.  Also `'0'` is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption that `char('0') == int(0)` and `char('1') == int(1)` just doesn't hold. In ASCII these characters have the values of 48 and 49.

What you should do to get integer values of digit characters is substract `'0'` instead of simple casting (`raw_string_int[x] = raw_string_char[x] - '0';`).

I think you have conceptual problems though. The array can't be full of valid values to the end (the corresponding C-string would at least contain a null-terminator, which is not a valid binary character). You can use the string's `size()` method to find out how many characters the string actually contains. And naturally you are risking buffer overflows, should the `binary` string contain `size` characters or more.

If the intention is to check if the input is a valid binary number, why can't you test the original string, why would you copy data around to two more arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You're printing every character in `raw_string_char`.  C-style strings go until the first zero character (that's `'\0'`, not `0`).

Change to `for (int i = 0; raw_string_char[i] != 0 && i < size; i++)`.

Comment: This is true, but not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, '0' is converted to an integer 48. You don't really need to convert the C++ string to a C style string. You can use iterators or the index operator [] on the C++ string. You also need to use logical AND && rather than logical OR || in your if statement.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>

void Number(std::string binary) {
    for(std::string::const_iterator i = binary.begin(); i != binary.end(); i++ )
        if( *i != '0' && *i != '1')
        {
        printf("ERROR NOT A BINARY NUMBER\n");
            return;
        }
}

int main() {
    Number("0001");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The raw_string_char is never initialized, the extra characters are possibly due to this.  Use memset to initialize the array.

```
memset(raw_string_array, 0, size);
```

Comment: This is not necessary.  strcpy adds a null terminator.

Comment: Procolus's answer is correct, I'll bet if you add that \n to the 1st printf you'll see 48 on a newline!